# Should "the" or "el" appear before a Spanish proper noun placed in an English text

Tags: proper-nouns, spanish, foreign-phrases

I have a textbook that refers to the Spanish royal road that linked Mexico City and Santa Fe as "El Camino Real", though the full name in Spanish is "El Camino Real de Tierra Adentro" to distinguish is from multiple other royal roads in the New World. This reference uses "El" everywhere instead of "The". There are English translations of the word, but I want to be precise and avoid confusion, so in my writing use the Spanish name, but I'm writing in English everywhere else. So I want to know which is correct to use:

1. **El** Camino Real de Tierra Adentro was a trade route that linked Mexico City and Santa Fe. Bob was a trader who sold his goods on **El** Camino Real de Tierra Adentro.

OR

1. **The** Camino Real de Tierra Adentro was a trade route that linked Mexico City and Santa Fe. Bob was a trader who sold his goods on **the** Camino Real de Tierra Adentro.

Can I equally use them both, or is one more correct?

Comment: Anecdotally, I generally see it as "El Camino Real..." _if_ the formal name of the road in English is "El Camino Real...". If the formal English name of the road is simply "Camino Real", I will generally see no article at all, or "the" may be used.

Comment: Even though I've never been there, I have a vague understanding of what "El Camino Real" is.  If you called it "the Camino Real" I would be fairly confused.

Answer (score 4):

The formal name in English of what used to be the main road from San Francisco to San Jose is *El Camino Real* (this is what you see on the street signs).

In addition, we very rarely put *the* in front of street names in English. You wouldn't say that the prime minister lives on the Downing Street. There are some streets which include *the* in their formal names (e.g. *The Pennsylvania Turnpike*), but they're rare. So saying *The Camino Real* is a strange mixture of Spanish and English, where you've translated *El* rather than dropping it, as would usually be done in English.

So I would recommend using *El*.

This doesn't necessarily apply to things other than street names ... in San Francisco, it's *The Presidio* rather than *El Presidio*.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily apply to street names either. The name of San Francisco's north-eastern waterfront(ish) boulevard is perversely _The Embarcadero_.